# Mouse-object-picking in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I managed to get a simple object picking example working with the [help of the stackoverflow community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65794285/problem-with-mouse-camera-raycasting-in-threejs).

The working code is [here](https://codepen.io/ThanosSar/pen/MWjxJdq).

But this example is a special case where the canvas fits the window.

If the canvas is smaller than the window and there is a left and top offset, the picking doesn't work (precisely).

How can the offset be corrected? What must be changed to make the picking fit again?

I tried some things including setting `renderer.setSize(threejsCanvas.clientWidth, threejsCanvas.clientHeight);` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `window.innerWidth` and `.innerHeight` to get the position of your raycaster:

```
  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
```

If the width of your canvas isn't `window.innerWidth`, then use the alternative size you're assigning. Also, you probably don't want to add the `"click"` event to `document`, you might want to add it to `renderer.domElement` so it only triggers when clicking on the canvas.